# What is HelperTool Code Signing Identity set for 3rd party Mac Developer Application?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, authorization, root

Please tell me what is Code Signing Identity set on HelperTool target for app distribute out site the Appstore.
Project Code Signing Identity
[image]
Project Target Code Signing Identity
[image]
HelperToolCode Signing Identity 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In build settings of your projects, set the code signing identity to *"Mac Developer"*, in order to distribute your app outside of the Mac App store, or as iOS Developer to distribute in the iOS App Store. Otherwise, just set it to 'Don't Code Sign' to disable code signing. I hope this helps!

Comment: Not working, still having same issue. (HelperTool installation failed)

Comment: Can you explain exactly what you did?

Comment: i have updated the Question, I am testing on sample Project

Comment: when i enter Password to HelperTool it show Error "The operation couldn’t be completed. (CFErrorDomainLaunchd error 4.): (null)"

Comment: In your project target, set the code signing to: "Mac Developer: *account_name (Team Code)*" Do the same for your app. For the HelperTool target, also set it to the  "Mac Developer: *account_name (Team Code)*". Clean, (cmd+shift+K), clean the build folder (cmd+opt+shift+K), and then re-build your project. Hopefully that will work!